# CSS Table Structure Issue

Tags: html, css

I am a noob in CSS and i was actually trying to create a table kind of structure using Html Div and CSS, but got stuck in one issue.

Problem is that I have put 4 columns in 1 single row. The last column contains a text area which is expandable. 
When I try to expand the text area, only the last column expands instead of the whole row.

Below is the code demo:

> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oIChn

Comment: If this is tabular data, why not use an actual table? Otherwise you'll want to look at using display: table-* attributes for your container divs. http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/

Answer (score 1):

The code isn't working because you arent following a table structure, which should (always) be:

```
table
-row
--cell
--/cell
-/row
/table
```

IN your code, you are using some `display:tablexx` CSS, however often in elements isolated from other aspects of the table structure they are expecting to be next to, as such the layout is broken.

The correct CSS/HTML structure is (e.g):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/gw8Dk/)

HTML

```
<div class='table'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
        <div class='cell'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table {
    display:table;
    height:100%;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
}
```

Note that using this there are no specific `thead` or `tbody` sections, you can simply adapt your CSS to style headers etc as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the end of your css, should do the trick

```
.r-tab-head{
display: table-row;
float: none;
}

.divCell {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
}
```